Device like a skateboard for adjusting speed of people who must walk on top of it
Some medication, such as gabapentin, can induce an involuntary and most often unstoppable need to walk; often at determined speeds. This, may be determined by how long someone has taken the medication for and by a given number of mandatory comfortable steps. The speed can be further modulated, to some extent, with sedating medication, which would have negative effects on cognition and the ability to do stuff in general. Gabapentin also affects cognition in some persons by turning down abilities. Both kinds of medication have adverse effects on cognition and overall funny m functioning and some persons may not be able to do an anything after taking them. Medication which may work in a sedating manner may be antipsychotics.
I wonder whether anyone has developed a tapis roulant (treadmill) device, shaped like some sort of skateboard, for these users and other users who may want to exercise, so that they make walk on top of it at a given speed, while, the wheels below, are propelled, at a different, speed (which may be lower or higher).
This would be useful for walking next to people who must walk at a different pace and you need the special skateboard to adjust the pace of walking to walk next to these people.
Has anyone engineered such a device?

Your question is too broad. Please edit it down to an engineering design question. You might explain what a "tapis roulant" is. (I had to look it up.) You might also explain how the user will apply force to the treadmill track relative to the chassis. (You'll need some sort of Zimmerframe to hold on to.)

Aren't there those shoes with wheels that do this?

Yes, this device does exist. It's often referred to as a walking bike or treadmill bike, and it's sold under the brand name Lopifit.
There are also elliptical bikes, which simulate a walking motion. These are more widely available. Brands include ElliptiGo and StreetStrider.
